# Windows store app deploy in new dev center

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to upload new version of my windows store app to the store but Microsoft has changed their submission portal and I'm not possible to find how I can do it.

I tried it through [Windows Dev Center](https://dev.windows.com/en-us) and there is this menu

[image]

Do you have any clue how to do new version in Microsoft Dev Center please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not obvious to me either.

To submit a new version of your app, go into the Dev Center and select your app from the left menu. In the app overview, you will see the menu as pictured in your question above. Click on *Submissions*, and you should see your current submission. Click on the *Update* action to create a new submission.

[image: submissions-screen]

Comment: thank for your reply but I do not have this option in submissions http://prntscr.com/8lg048

Comment: From your screen capture, you have already clicked on the Update link.  It says you have a new submission in progress.  That is the submission that you should update with your new code/ descriptions/ etc and that you should submit.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had to finish my submission in progress. Thank you